# Не могу реализовать "прыжок" в основную программу Bootloder'ом (stm32)

Tags: c, stm32

Пишу собственный загрузчик, на текущем этапе прошивка которую он записывает хранится в массиве 4хбайтных значений. Запись происходит как надо. Но функция "прыжка" на адрес новой прошивки укладывает мой код в `HardFault_Handler`

Массив новой прошивки:

```
uint32_t data[]={
0x10, 0x04, 0x00, 0x20, 0x9D, 0x01, 0x01, 0x08, 
0xF3, 0x0A, 0x01, 0x08, 0xEF, 0x0A, 0x01, 0x08, 
0xF1, 0x0A, 0x01, 0x08, 0x85, 0x02, 0x01, 0x08, 
0x05, 0x0C, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x17, 0x0B, 0x01, 0x08, 
0x87, 0x02, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x15, 0x0B, 0x01, 0x08, 0x19, 0x0B, 0x01, 0x08...............
```

Как она ложится в память:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код прыжка:

(`#define MAIN_PROGRAM_START_ADDRESS              (uint32_t)0x08010000`)

```
    typedef     void        (*pFunction)(void);
    uint32_t  JumpAddress = *(__IO uint32_t*)(MAIN_PROGRAM_START_ADDRESS + 4);
    pFunction Jump = (pFunction)JumpAddress;

    HAL_RCC_DeInit();
    HAL_DeInit();

    SysTick->CTRL = 0;
    SysTick->LOAD = 0;
    SysTick->VAL  = 0;

#if (SET_VECTOR_TABLE)
    SCB->VTOR = MAIN_PROGRAM_START_ADDRESS;
#endif

    __set_MSP(*(__IO uint32_t*)MAIN_PROGRAM_START_ADDRESS);
    Jump();
```

Сюда прилетаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите какими средствами отладки можно попробовать понять из-за чего трудности?
Или если есть идеи, то в чем может быть загвостка?

(Прошивка - обычное мигание светодиода по delay без любых прерываний)

Comment: А начать с осмотра и частичной модификации `под себя` стандартного загрузчика? И чисто предположение, откуда вы выбрали адрес `MAIN_PROGRAM_START_ADDRESS` и смещение `+4` в `JumpAddress` ? `objdump`ом смотрели собранное по адресам и смещениям?

Comment: А почему она у вас ложиться в память один байт через 3 нуля ? Ни один процессор не использует код в таком виде. это же дикая потеря памяти. Вы получили дамп идущих подряд байт, так и запишите его в память как байты идущие непосредственно друг за другом, что бы в дампе памяти они выглядели так же как в файле

Comment: Как заметил @Mike, у вас неправильно записываются данные во флеш. Или замените `uint32_t data[]={` на `uint8_t data[]={`, или перепишите все исходные данные как 32-битные значения `uint32_t data[] = { 0x20000410, 0x0801019D, ... }`.

Comment: @Mike, Embedder спасибо, друзья, проблема правда была в этом, почему то он писал не по 4 байта а по 16, либо я ошибался в том, что максимальное значение 4х байт 0xFF

Comment: @Denisok Да, во втором вы точно ошибались. Максимальное значение 4х байт 0xFFFFFFFF ... :)